# How do I use a drupal views field value as Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, drupal-7

I have set up a views in Drupal 7 that outputs the value of a field, but I don't know how to pass on this field value to use as a variable in Javascript.

I know that for nodes I could simple do:

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($view_mode == 'full') {
    $setting = array('MYMODULE' => array('currentNid' => $node->nid));
    $node->content['#attached']['js'][] = array(
      'data' => $setting,
      'type' => 'setting',
    );
  }
}
```

and then in Javascript :`var currentNid = Drupal.settings.MYMODULE.currentNid;`

I really want to know how to do this with views fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this solution just in case someone needs it in the future.

MODULE.module

```
function MODULE_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['view']->name == 'VIEW_NAME' && $vars['view']->current_display == 
'DISPLAY_NAME') {
    //dpm($vars); use the devel module to expose available variable
  $myVar = $vars['fields']['uid']->content;
  drupal_add_js(array('MODULE' => array('mykey' => $myVar)), array('type' => 'setting'));
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE') . '/MODULE.js');
  }
}
```

MODULE.JS

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.MODULE = {
attach: function(context,settings) {

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert(settings.MODULE.mykey);
});
}}})(jQuery);
```